# Return multiple values in varchar2

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to return the values of several columns (With a function) in a varchar2 but I get an error when I choose several columns in select.

```
FUNCTION FU_PRUEBAS (P_IDNUM MAC.IDNUM%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS REGISTRO VARCHAR2(100);
     BEGIN
     select NOMBRES, FECHANACIMIENTO INTO REGISTRO
     from MAC WHERE IDNUM = P_IDNUM;
     RETURN REGISTRO;
```

**Error:**

> Error(17,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(18,6): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: there are not enough values

Comment: what error? Can you added in your question?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What do you want the function to return?

Comment: I want the function to return several columns of the record according to the ID entered. For example, I want to save the name and birthday of the person with ID 5 in the VARCHAR "Return".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two relatively simple options - if they suit your needs. You didn't really explain what you expect to get as a result so - this might, or might not be applicable to your situation.

Anyway, here you go:

First option uses `listagg` function which returns a *concatenated* string (as you wanted to return `varchar2`). Drawback is that it won't work for the result longer than 4000 characters, but - in that case - you can use `XMLAGG`.

```
SQL> create or replace function fu_pruebas (par_deptno in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    select listagg(ename, ', ') within group (order by ename)
  7      into retval
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select fu_pruebas(10) result from dual;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK, KING, MILLER

SQL>
```

---

Another one concatenates different columns into a string; you might need to use e.g. `to_char` or `to_date` functions in certain cases, but - generally - it works as follows:

```
SQL> create or replace function fu_pruebas_2 (par_empno in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    select ename ||' - '|| job ||' - '|| sal
  7      into retval
  8      from emp
  9      where empno = par_empno;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select fu_pruebas_2(7654) result from dual;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MARTIN - SALESMAN - 1250

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need  a multiple values retunr you need  a proper object

```
  create or replace
     type your_obj as object
       ( val_1 varchar2(200),
         val_2 varchar2(200)
       );
```

then

```
  FUNCTION FU_PRUEBAS (P_IDNUM MAC.IDNUM%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS REGISTRO VARCHAR2(100);
     BEGIN
     select NOMBRES, FECHANACIMIENTO INTO your_var1, your_var2
     from MAC WHERE IDNUM = P_IDNUM
     RETURN your_obj(your_var1, your_var2)
     END;
```